# How to make a new prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, prediction

Let me explain, i'm working with an Artificial Neural Network.
This model has 15 variables, 14 independents and one dependent.
In the independent variables i've 3 categorical variables 
`(day of week, month, direction(north,south, etc...))`.
I already enconde them `(monday = 1, tuesday = 2, and so...),` 
also i hot encode them 
`(monday = [1,0,0,0], tuesday = [0,1,0,0])`.

My question is, How can i make a prediction with new values, somethig like this.

```
X=['Monday','January','South']
```

Here is the code

```
# Classification template

# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset

dataset = pd.read_csv('clean.csv')

X = dataset.iloc[:, [4,5,6,9,12,15,16]].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 14].values

#Encoding categorical Data
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelenconder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:,1] = labelenconder_X.fit_transform(X[:,1])

labelenconder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:,2] = labelenconder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:,2])

labelenconder_X_7 = LabelEncoder()
X[:,4] = labelenconder_X_7.fit_transform(X[:,4])

labelenconder_X_9 = LabelEncoder()
X[:,5] = labelenconder_X_9.fit_transform(X[:,5])

labelenconder_X_10 = LabelEncoder()
X[:,6] = labelenconder_X_10.fit_transform(X[:,6])

onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[1,2,4,5,6])

X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()

X = X[:, 1:]



# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling
#from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
#sc = StandardScaler()
#X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
#X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

# Fitting classifier to the Training set
# Create your classifier here
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense


classifier = Sequential()

                    #INPUT LAYER AND HIDDEN LAYER
classifier.add(Dense(units = 5, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim =9))

                    #ADDING SECOND HIDDEN LAYER
classifier.add(Dense(units = 5, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation =  'relu'))

                    #adding output node 
classifier.add(Dense(units= 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))

                    #Applygin Stochasting Gradient Descent

classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size =28, epochs = 100)


classifier.save('ANN2.h5')
model = keras.models.load_model('ANN2.h5')
y_predict = model.predict(X_test)
y_predict = (y_predict > 0.40)
```

Comment: Are you working with a library? Have you implemented this by hand? If so can we know which library or see some code. I don't think this question is answerable with the information presented.

Comment: there is the code.

Comment: Im wondering if there is some way to know which combination of [0,0,0,1,0] corresponds to which value or if i can just give it a String(in the categorical variables) and  change it according to the binary code it corresponds

Answer (score 0):

If you want to encode all days of the week for a prediction, monday should probably be `[1,0,0,0,0,0,0]`. Or you use regression (0.0 - 6.0) instead of classification.

But, since you used `X` instead of `y` here, I'm not sure if your provided `X=['Monday','January','South']` is meant to be the input rather than the output (`y`). If it is, you do not need a one-hot encoding and you can just encode as e.g. `X=[0,0,2]` with

- Monday 0
- Tuesday 1
- ...
- January 0
- February 1
- North 0
- East 1
- ...

I agree with @morsecodist that more information is needed for a proper answer to your question.